# Replace a character till fixed position in a file by batch command

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, command

I hava a file. that contains values like

```
E:\ABC\XYZ1\1231\AAA\SSS\name1.sql
E:\ABC\XYZ2\1232\AAA\TTT\name2.sql
E:\ABC\XYZ3\1233\AAA\UUU\name3.sql
E:\ABC\XYZ4\1234\AAA\YYY\name4.sql
E:\ABC\XYZ5\1235\AAA\ZZZ\name5.sql
```

and i have to rearrange these values like

```
@SSS\name1.sql
@TTT\name2.sql
@UUU\name3.sql
@YYY\name4.sql
@ZZZ\name5.sql
```

(edit - improved format)

Comment: try the command : `for /?` for help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this (change the name oft the input file):

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "fname=test.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%fname%) do (
    set "fname=%%~nxi"
    set "fpath=%%~dpi"
    set "fpath=!fpath:~0,-1!
    for %%j in (!fpath!) do set "fpath=%%~nxj"
    echo @!fpath!\!fname!
)
endlocal
```

.. and if the path structure is always the same use the command line:

```
for /f "tokens=6,7delims=\" %i in (test.txt) do @echo @%i\%j
```

Comment: +1, Your first code can be simplified to a command line one liner: `for /f "delims=" %A in (test.txt) do @for %B in ("%A\..") do @echo @%~nxB\%~nxA`